# How to mark a variable as initialized at the language level?

Tags: c++, initialization, static-analysis, legacy-code

I am using a linked C-library to get values into a variable.

```
void f_wrapper(int& v){
   auto s = f_legacy(&v);
   if(s != success) throw std::runtime_error{};
}

...

  int value;  // clang-tidy complains here: using "variable 'value' is not initialized"
  f_wrapper(value);
```

**However, clang-tidy complains here: using "variable 'value' is not initialized".**

As far as understand, this is simply because the compiler cannot see through the linked function.

I don't want to do `int value = 0` (because I trust that the library will initialize `value` and I believe in "partially formed" values.)
Also, I am looking not to add  `// NOLINT(warning)` just to suppress the warning.
(The pattern repeats often.)

**Is there something I could do mark `value` as initialized *in the language*?**

I am looking for something like:

```
void f_wrapper(int& v) {
   auto s = f_legacy(&v);
   if(s != success) throw std::runtime_error{};
   [[mark initialized(v)]];
}
```

Worst case I can do this *inside the wrapper*, because at least I don't see the unnecessary initialization the main code, but it is very cumbersome in cases where arrays are initialized. Also I don't want to pay the prize of this initialization or choose a default value.

```
void f_wrapper(int& v) {
   v = int{};  // initialize to suppress warning at high level code
   auto s = f_legacy(&v);
   if(s != success) throw std::runtime_error{};
}
```

Comment: Related question: [How to avoid clang-tidy warnings about uninitialized variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/68526284/1678770).

Comment: @Human-Compiler, that question shows that the warning appears even for pure C++ code (use of `std::stream`'s  `>>`). This is the prototypical pattern of (Stepanov's) partially formed variables. If this is not even accepted it is all lost for the idiom.

Comment: that's why I only said it's related and not a duplicate. It still has to do with silencing the warning, but the answer is also effectively the same; you have to perform _some_ initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not what you want to hear, but there's really only *one* way to initialize a variable "at the language level" in standard C++ -- and that's to *initialize it*. It really is that straight-forward. You're basically stuck with either this, or `NOLINT`ing it, as you've already described in your question. It's not a glamorous solution, and it's not what you're after; but there really aren't any better ways.

I'm sure there may be ways to "trick" the tooling into thinking it's initialized, but any such suggestions would amounts to hacks at best.

That said; assuming the `clang-tidy` check causing grief is the [`cppcoreguidelines-init-variables`](https://clang.llvm.org/extra/clang-tidy/checks/cppcoreguidelines-init-variables.html) rule, it's worth noting that this *only* triggers for integers, booleans, floats, doubles, and pointers -- and the cost to default-initialize such a value is generally negligible. Unless you've benchmarked this cost and found default-initializing this to be a *true bottleneck*, there's very little reason to avoid this practice.

In general, initializing the variable is the cleanest / safest way to silence this issue, and is ultimately the best practice *anyway*. Without initializing, all it takes is a *small* bug in `f_legacy` to cause unexpected UB. If `f_legacy` has any bugs such that it returns success but forgets to set a value to `v`, then `v` will not be initialized and will formally be UB -- and this is all just to save default-initializing a primitive.

---

**Just a suggestion:**

Rather than `NOLINT`ing the callers or having to initialize someone-else's uninitialized value, as per your "worst-case" `f_wrapper` example, could the API possibly be altered to *return* the initialized value rather than initialize what is passed in?

If you did this, you could either `NOLINT` it internally, so there are less `NOLINT`s required, or just initialize the value yourself to prevent other potential issues. Since the value is encapsulated in the function, this would be much less egregious than initializing the caller's maybe-uninitialized value, in my opinion:

```cpp
int f_wrapper() {
   auto v = int{};
   auto s = f_legacy(&v);
   if(s != success) throw std::runtime_error{};

   return v;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  I didn't mention, but the worst part of initializing these variables is that then runtime tools like `valgrind` do not really detect use of uninitialized variables (because, well, they are initialized to something.)